# ios - How to merge two different sections in collection view

Tags: ios, swift, cells, collectionview

I want to merge two different sections that uses two different cells respectively(cellA and cellB). Using the following code I could get a collection view with two sections.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{

    @IBOutlet var testCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.testCollectionView.delegate = self
        self.testCollectionView.dataSource = self
    }
   
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 {
            return 3
        } else {
            return 1
        }
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "taskCell", for: indexPath) as! CellA
            cell.layer.cornerRadius = 2
            cell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red:0.82, green:0.82, blue:0.82, alpha:1.0).cgColor
            cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
            cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
            cell.layer.shadowRadius = 4
            cell.layer.masksToBounds = false
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell2 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "addNewCell", for: indexPath) as! CellB
            return cell2
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        
        let width = testCollectionView.bounds.width/2 - 30
        let height = width
        
        return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(30, 20, 10, 20)
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 20
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(indexPath.row)
    }
}
```

And the output looks like this.

[image]

Now, I want the section 1(CellB) to be merged with section 0(CellA). Like this.

[image]

I couldn't find the solution to achieve this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I believe you would just remove `Cell B` from section 1 and then create a new one with the same data in section 0.

Comment: Are you talking about an animation that moves Cell B to section A or one section with four cells in the initial state?

Comment: In `cellForItem` method, work out how many cell A there need to be (based on your data), then when `indexPath.item` would represent the next cell, make it a Cell B. Do a similar thing in the `numberOfItemsInSection` method to get one more than the number of Cell A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show both cell types in the same section with these changes:

1. Add properties for the number of `aCells` and `bCells`.  This is better than putting the *magic numbers* `3` and `1` in your code because it documents what the numbers represent.  If you ever need to change them, you can change them in one spot.
2. Change `numberOfSections` to return `1`.
3. Change `numberOfItemsInSection` to return the sum of the number of A cells and the number of B cells:  `return aCells + bCells`.
4. In `cellForItemAt`, compare `indexPath.item` to `aCells` to figure out when to switch over to B cells.

---

```
var aCells = 3
var bCells = 1

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return aCells + bCells
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if indexPath.item < aCells {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "taskCell", for: indexPath) as! CellA
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 2
        cell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red:0.82, green:0.82, blue:0.82, alpha:1.0).cgColor
        cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
        cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        cell.layer.shadowRadius = 4
        cell.layer.masksToBounds = false
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell2 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "addNewCell", for: indexPath) as! CellB
        return cell2
    }
}
```